# Text input keyboard type with options for 'bold', 'italic', 'underline' text - ipad

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-textinput, react-native-text

Is there any way to show the Bold/Italic/Underline buttons in the keyboard when focusing a TextInput on an iPad? I've seen this option already built in in the mail and notes apps, however I cannot find any way to do this for my app using React Native. The image below shows the keyboard type that I am looking for:

[image: Image - Keyboard with Bold/Italic/Underline options]